# Is it possible to auto-save a file when focus is switch to another tab?

Tags: auto-save

I am not sure that this possible but I have I two splitted panes while using `tmux` inside `iTerm2` and I am using `emacs daemon`. I am using `iTerm`'s keybinding to switch between tabs.

One one of them `emacs` is open and on the another one `shell` is open.

```
---------------
|file  |$     |
|      |      |
|      |      |
---------------
```

I usually make a change on the file and switch to other tab (that is on `shell`) to run the test.

- During this whenever I switch to other tab is it possible for `emacs` to save the file automatically triggered by the iTerm's keybinding to switch between tabs without using `C-x C-s`?
- If not from the shell can I force emacs save all its open files right before running its tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that Emacs running in a terminal cannot observe GUI events such as switching to another tab. If you want Emacs to observe GUI events, run a GUI Emacs.

(This may be possible using a companion program, but even so this would depend to some extent on the goodwill of iTerm2. If it's at all possible, it's not easy and
may have side effects in conditions that you may or may not care about such as attaching Emacs windows to terminals provided by different terminal emulators.)

On the other hand, it's pretty easy to remotely ask Emacs to save. This assumes that you're running the Emacs server: either start Emacs with `emacs --daemon` or run `(server-start)` from your init file. To remotely ask Emacs to save all buffers, run the shell command

```
emacsclient -e '(save-some-buffers t)'
```

Comment: Can we run `emacsclient -c '(save-some-buffers t)'` without opening the emacs's buffer window and just do the saving?

Comment: @alper That doesn't open a window. Except it's `-e`, not `-c`, sorry.

Comment: `emacsclient -e '(save-some-buffers t)'` does not do anything and freezes on my end

Comment: @alper Are you running the server? Does Emacs display any messages (check the `*Messages*` buffer)? What version of Emacs are you running?

Comment: Yes sir I am running emacs daemon on the background as `emacsclient -qut -e filename.txt` ; I believe this automatically starts running emacs daemon on the backgorund. I cannot check `*Messages*` section. Running `emacsclient -e '(save-some-buffers t)'` just freezes in the terminal and does not do anything

Comment: @alper Is it a generic problem with emacsclient or a problem with `save-some-buffers`? What happens when you run `emacsclient -e '(+ 2 2)'` ? And with `emacsclient -e '(message "hello")'` : `hello` should appear in the output of emacsclient, and also in the minibuffer line of the active Emacs frame, and also in the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: Ah I find what the problem is on my end. I was trying it on remotely connected machine. `emacsclient` was aliased to `emacsclient -c` so `emacsclient -e '(+ 2 2)'` was opening a emacs's GUI. If xquartz is not running in the background it was just freezing, I think waiting response from xquartz to open. `command emacsclient -e '(+ 2 2)'` prints 4 and other prints `hello` . `command emacsclient -e '(save-some-buffers t)'` prints `nil`, I assume it saves the buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `after-focus-change-function`. You can advise this function with an `:before` function to save all buffers. That's easily accomplished by using an anonymous function like:

```
(lambda () (save-some-buffers t))
```

like @alper suggested. You can use the `advice-add` function or the `define-advice` macro like so

```
(advice-add 'after-focus-change-function :before #'(lambda () (save-some-buffers t)))
```

or

```
(define-advice after-focus-change-function (:before ())
  (save-some-buffers t))
```

Answer (score 0):

[super-save-mode](https://github.com/bbatsov/super-save) to saves the buffer automatically when focus moves away from it.

I do not use emacs in terminals, so I do not know if this works out of the box there, but I am pretty sure it can be configured to do what you want.

Comment: It didn't work for the tab toggle in between the iTerm tabs